# Converting a C# Lambda Expr to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

I found the following C# statement for returning just the digits in a string:

```
    txt = txt.Where(c >= Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray();
```

How can this be done in VB.NET? So far, I have been told on the use of '>=' that '=>' is not defined for types 'Char' and Boolean...

My interpretation is that the Char.ToArray converts the resultant series of Chars to a single String. I am not sure about that, either.

Comment: `txt = txt.Where( Function (c) Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C# code is not correct as is, you mixed up the order of `=>` (i.e. you have `>=`):

```
txt = txt.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray();
```

Here is the VB.NET:

```
txt = txt.Where(Function(c) [Char].IsDigit(c)).ToArray()
```

Here is what I used:

http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Okay.  I just copy/pasted from Telerik.

Comment: That code converter is going to come in VERY handy! Thanks Rory!